# Plotly and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am working with Plotly library. Below you can see the code for producing Treemap.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

dt=data.frame(
          types= rep("stories",10),
          kind= c('kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1'),
          values=seq(1:10))

Treemap<-plot_ly(data = dt,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~values,
                 labels= ~kind,
                 parents=  ~types,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")%>%
    layout(title="Treemap")

Treemap
```

So the above code shows us Treemap with a title. This title has different font in comparison with plots from the ggplot2 library. Below you can see one example of a chart in ggplot2 with some title

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(values, kind, data = dt)+ ggtitle("Treemap")
```

So can anybody help me how to change the title in Treemap with Plotly library and to have a title in the same font as the title in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the default font for `ggplot` is Arial/Helvetica. You can change the font in `plotly` by adding `font` in your `layout`. You can use the following code:

```
library(plotly)
t <- list(
  family = "Arial")

Treemap<-plot_ly(data = dt,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~values,
                 labels= ~kind,
                 parents=  ~types,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")%>%
  layout(title="Treemap", font = t)

Treemap
```

Output:

[image]

You can change the `font` to whatever you want if available.

#### Comment: Add bold to title

To add a bold title you can use html tags like this:

```
Treemap<-plot_ly(data = dt,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~values,
                 labels= ~kind,
                 parents=  ~types,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")%>%
  layout(title="<b>Treemap</b>", font = t)

Treemap
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried but again I can see differences. How I can put bold font because in the ggplot2 titles are in bold ?

Comment: @silent_hunter, I added code to the answer. You can use HTML tags to make your title bold.